# What does "outset" mean in this context?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm studying Principles of Mathematical Analysis written by Rudin.

I encountered the word "outset" while I was studying Lebesgue integration.

The word "outset" appears in page317 of PMA.

[image]

I can only find the general meaning of outset in the internet, which is "the beginning" according to cambridge dictionary.

I guess there is a formal definition in math regarding the word "outset".

Is there anyone who knows the meaning of "outset" in this context?

"In most cases we therefore do not lose any generality if we assume the given functions to be finite-valued from the **outset**."

Comment: it’s not a formal math word. The dictionary definition is what is intended. He’s simply saying that when dealing with integrable functions, there is no loss of generality in assuming that the functions take values in $\Bbb{R}$ (rather than the a-priori assumption of functions taking values in $[-\infty,\infty]$), i.e you may as well assume right from the beginning that you’re dealing with real-valued functions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I'm sorry. I'm not a native english speaker. So I have a little difficulty in interpreting your answer. What's the difference between $\mathbb{R}$ and $[-\infty, +\infty]$? 
Does the statement mean that we don't have to explicitly mention the assumption because lebesgue integrable function implies finite-valued function?

Comment: $\Bbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers (redundant, but for more emphasis these are the finite real numbers), while $[-\infty,\infty]$ is the “extended real number system”, i.e includes infinites. Rudin definitely explains the difference between the two. Lebesgue integrable implies **a.e** finite-valued, i.e you can modify on a set of maeasure zero to make it finite-valued. And modifying by measure zero sets doesn’t affect the theory of integration which is why we always make the assumption, without explicit mention (and without loss of generality) that the functions are finite-valued.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you! Now I have more clear understanding of the sentence!